# What is the expectation of ‘the number. of coin flips until any string of 4 is repeated’, but each pattern can overlap?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809391/coin-flip-what-is-the-expectation-of-the-n0-of-coin-flips-to-get-a-repeated-pa) but did not get a reply, I am very keen to know how its done.

I think I worded it poorly.

You can flip a coin unlimited times.

There are ($2^{4} = 16$) blocks of 4, eg. HHTT, HHHH.

What is the expectation of ‘the number. of coin flips until any pattern is repeated’, but each pattern can overlap?

So HHHHH , would count as (HHHH)H and H(HHHH)

Comment: This does not look simple but it does look small enough to count empirically.  As you say, there are $2^4=16$ possible patterns of four, so after $20$ flips you must have a repeated pattern as $20-3=17 \gt 16$, and $2^{20} =  1048576$ is easily treated in a computer

Comment: It seems that for patterns of two rather than four, the probability you use $3$ flips and find a repeat is $\frac14$, the probability of $4$ flips is $\frac14$, of $5$ flips is $\frac38$, and of $6$ flips is $\frac18$, making the expected number of flips $\frac{35}{8}$

Comment: ...so we need the expectation for the number of steps, so that **some** pattern (among all 16 patterns) is (for the first time) repeated?!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2734550/147256

Comment: Instead of posting a new question that’s a rewording of the old one, you should update that old one with the better wording.